# Make a git repository that anyone can commit to directly

Tags: git, github

I'm making an open source repository and I want it to be really easy for anyone to contribute. Requiring people to fork and clone for any contribution would be a problem, as would having to add collaborators manually.

My original plan was to use github and set `master` as a protected branch with a status check that only I can control. Anyone could clone the original repo just once, and whenever they wanted to make a contribution they could just branch from `master` and make a pull request. My approval would still be required to merge the pull request via the status check on `master`. However I can't see any way to make everyone a collaborator.

Is there a way to use github to support this functionality? Is there a good (i.e. one that won't discourage contributors) alternative git hosting service that can do this?

Comment: If you think forking is already enough to put off your contributors, just imagine how annoyed they will be when some anonymous troll replaces every word in your project by the N-word (just an example), and you've pretty much made it impossible to stop that troll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is requiring people to fork and clone a problem, but allowing anyone to clone your repository, make changes, and then push *their* changes to *your* repository a better solution?

GitHub's forking model is good because it allows contributors to clone your code, and pull any changes that are made to your repository, yet prevents anyone from directly modifying your repository. When a contributor is ready to push their changes, they can push it to their own fork and submit a pull request.

What happens when you create another branch with code that is not ready for master? Do you really want **everyone** to be able to push to this branch (or be able to delete this branch and potentially lose all your work)?

Take a look at the [forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow).

Comment: OK, there's something I've been missing. Say someone forks, clones, changes, and I merge a pull request. Then I make a bunch of changes in my official repo. Can they easily update their fork to merge in the central changes? I thought that they would have to fork and clone from scratch. My git is still pretty poor.

Comment: I've looked around a bit and I see now that yes, it is very easy to do that. Thanks for helping me realise.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Gitlab, it's a free alternative for Github and it has roles included so you can control the access for every contributor.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see any way to open up the repo for **everyone**.